# Creating an application specific log under Tomcat 7?

Tags: log4j, tomcat7

I'm trying to capture logging messages, stdout, and stderr for my webapp, which is running under Tomcat 7.

I have a log4j.properties file in my war file, at WEB-IN/classes/log4j.properties, pretty much copied from the log4j docs, except with a filename "myapp.log":

```
# Set root logger level to DEBUG and its only appender to A1.
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, A1

# A1 is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.File=${catalina.home}/logs/myapp.log

# A1 uses PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

WEB-INF/lib includes log4j-1.2.14.jar and commons-logging-1.0.4.

I'm expecting to see myapp.log appear in Tomcat's log directory, but it's not. Please explain to me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a `ConsoleAppender` where you should be using a file appender:

```
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
```